# Alamofire - add both query parameter and body

Tags: ios, swift, rest, alamofire

I am trying to send a request that should contain both URL parameters and request body in JSON. Backend doesn't recognize the request and returns 400 status code.

This is how I tried to solve the problem

```swift
enum MyRequestsRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

    case RequestA(paramA: String, bodyInJsonString: String),
         RequestB(paramB: String)

    var baseURL: URL {
        URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8080")!
    }

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .RequestA: return .post
        case .RequestB: return .get
        }
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .RequestA: return "/api/a"
        case .RequestB: return "/api/b"
        }
    }

    var parameters: Parameters? {
        switch self {
        case .RequestA(let paramA, let bodyInJsonString):
            return [
                "paramA": paramA
            ]

        case .RequestB(let paramB):
            return ["paramB": paramB]

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.method = method

        switch self {
        case let .RequestA(paramA, bodyInJsonString):
            // here I am specifying `paramA` value
            request = try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters)

            // here body is already serialized to Json
            request.httpBody = Data(bodyInJsonString.utf8)
            request.setValue("application/json", "Content-Type")

        case let .RequestB(paramB):
            request = try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters)
            
        }

        return request
    }

}
```

And this is how I am making API call

```swift
let json: Data = try JSONEncoder().encode(notSerializedBodyObject)
let jsonString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)

AF.request(MyRequestsRouter.RequestA(paramA: "paramA", bodyInJsonString: jsonString!)).response { response in
            print("Request: \(response.request)")
            print("Response: \(response.response)")
            print("Error: \(response.error)")
            
            // etc
            }
            
}
```

As you can see the request URL is supposed to be 
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/a?paramA=paramA` plus request body in JSON. But response is 400 Bad request.

How to properly configure Alomofire?

Comment: It's unclear. Your issue is with A or B? Because you don't set httpBody in case of A., and in B, since it's a GET, it's quite strange to put httpBody...

Comment: @Larme, sorry, yes I edited the question. The problem is with request A.

Comment: Could you add `AF.request(...).cURLDescription { print("cURL: \($0) }.response { ...}` and see what's the output of cURL? Just to check where have been set the params, and if it's correct.

Comment: @Larme, in output I see  `-d "{ correct JSON }"`. And in the last line I see API url, but without `paramA` parameter: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire's `URLEncoding` has an initializer that gets `destination` as parameter. Based on documentation:

> `Destination` defining where the encoded query string will be applied.
> `.methodDependent` by default.

By default `.methodDependent` case checks the HTTP method of the request and **only** on `.get`, `.head` and `.delete` requests it encodes the passed parameters in the URL.

Given that fact, you never see `paramA` in your request (not even in the body) because you override it in the following line:

```
// here body is already serialized to Json
request.httpBody = Data(bodyInJsonString.utf8)
```

So, instead of using the **default** `URLEncoding`, you can simply call `URLEncoding`'s initializer directly passing as `destination` the `.queryString` case like this:

```
// here I am specifying `paramA` value
request = try URLEncoding(destination: .queryString).encode(request, with: parameters)

// here body is already serialized to Json
request.httpBody = Data(bodyInJsonString.utf8)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

That way you will have a request with `paramA` in the URL and your JSON as a body.